# how to find our creation order of pthreads?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am using C++ and pthreads and I need to find out the order in which a pthread was created, I need to have an unique integer that tells me which pthread was created first, second and so on.

My first idea was to use `pthread_self()`, however although this function returns a unique id that is pretty much a huge random-like number.

My second idea was to pass the counter I was using in the create method in the loop:

```
pthread_t pthreads[pthreadsNum]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < pthreadsNum; i++){
        if (pthread_create(&pthreads[i], NULL, process, (void *)&i) != 0){
            cerr << "Error in pthread creation" << endl;
            return PTHREAD_CREATION_FAILED;
        }
    }
```

However, this also does not work. In in my function `process` I try to print the value of the `i` counter but I get a mixed confusion. Apparently the counter gets updated while some pthreads are receiving it and chaos rules:

```
void *process(void* arg_ptr)
{
  int i = *((int*)arg_ptr);
  cout << i << endl;
  //rest of code
}
```

Giving me the random output:
3
3
4
3
And other combinations of this same random output.

In conclusion I have the following questions:

1 - What am I doing wrong?

2 - How can I pass the counter in a safe and efficient way?

3 - Is there another solution to get the order in which the pthreads were created?

Thanks in advance for any help :S

Comment: Just so it's said, if you care too much about the order stuff happens in, you might want to skip threading altogether.  You don't micromanage threads; you unleash them.  In order to make them worthwhile, you have to give up quite a bit of control over things like the order in which they run.

Comment: This is for a school project and I am required to use pthreads to calculated the PI number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the counter gets updated while some pthreads are receiving it and chaos rules

Yes that's what you end up with when using parallelism without synchronization: things never happen in the order you expect them to.

In your very situation an easy way to pass your counter to your thread is to cast it to a pointer. To ensure that the integer type you use is the same size as a pointer, use `uintptr_t` (the standard guarantees conversion between pointers and (u)intptr_t without any loss):

```
#include <stdint.h>

for (uintptr_t i = 0; i < pthreadsNum; ++i) {
    if (pthread_create(&pthreads[i], NULL, process, reinterpret_cast<void*>(i)) != 0) {
        ...
```

and

```
void* process(void* arg_ptr) {
    uintptr_t i = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(arg_ptr);
    ...
```

But cHao's comment is very spot-on: if you need this much control over the order of execution of your threads then you have a problem.
Better use synchronization (mutexes, condition variables and what not) to protect the critical data structures that are used for inter-thread communication (eg. message queues, other complex objects or even simple scalars) and you won't need this fine control.

Comment: But will this solution fix the chaos caused by the race condition? :S

Comment: Read carefully the code, and you will see that we are not passing the counter by reference anymore, but by value. So yeah each thread will know in which order it has been created (which was your question). However, this will definitely NOT prevent threads to run out of order (eg. you could get 3 1 4 2 as a result), you'd need to use synchronization for that.

Comment: Thanks, I tried out your solution and it gives me everything I need :D
Just out of curiosity is there a uintptr_t version for doubles?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I don't think so. To be honest I used `uintptr_t` because it fits exactly your question, sure, but the *most* common way to pass arguments to threads is more like @zzk showed you since it enables "two-way" communication through the shared variables (provided you add synchronization) and it is not restricted to the size of a pointer. If you want to pass anything that is not a pointer or equivalent (`(u)intptr_t`) type then you'll have to use a variant of his solution.

Comment: Alrigth then thanks! I have complete my school program to calculate PI with running 100000000 iteration and 4 pthreads in only 2.7 seconds. If you guys want I can share the code, maybe it can help someone out to see how I fixed the problem using your solution. Don't know if it would be a good idea though, I am not sure where to post it xD

Answer (score 2):

you passed in the address of `i`, and when your threads read the value of `i`, it could have well been changed. Because the threads you created and the main thread that running the loop and updating the value of `i` run in parallel.

If I were doing this, I would do like this:

```
pthread_t pthreads[pthreadsNum];
int ids[pthreadsNum];
for(int i = 0; i < pthreadsNum; i++){
    ids[i] = i;
    if (pthread_create(&pthreads[i], NULL, process, (void *)&ids[i]) != 0){
```

Comment: A very nice solution, I wonder why I didn't think of it before xD

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix if you could just go ahead and accept the answer, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a pair of questions: why do you need this information? What problem are you trying to solve?

With that said, why not simply wrap `pthread_create` around a function, which maintains some data structure (e.g. an std::vector<> or a linked list). The wrapper calls pthread_create, and adds the thread id of each created thread into the data structure? Remember to add some locking/serialization. And code to remove threads that have exited, if that's a requirement.

Finally, when you need the "order" of creation, simply find the "index" of the thread id in your data structure.